# Why I got NullPointerException when I run JUnit test of gnupg-for-java?

Tags: java, junit, gnupg, gpgme

I have to exchange encrypted and signed files with customer using GnuPG and Java.

So I downloaded and compiled Java JNI binding to the gpgme library:
https://github.com/guardianproject/gnupg-for-java

But when I runt test suite it fails:

```
$ ant test
...
test:
   [delete] Deleting directory /tmp/gnupg-for-java-tests
   [delete] Deleting directory /tmp/gnupg-for-java-tests
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/gnupg-for-java-tests
     [java] Executing '/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/jre/bin/java' with arguments:
     [java] '-Djava.library.path=/java_gnupg/build'
     [java] '-classpath'
     [java] '/java_gnupg/build/gnupg-for-java-0.2-pre.jar:/java_gnupg/build/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/java_gnupg/build/junit-4.12.jar:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGContext.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGData.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGException.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGGenkeyResult.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGKey.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGPeer.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/GnuPGSignature.class:/java_gnupg/build/classes/com/freiheit/gnupg/tests/GnuPGTestSuite.class'
     [java] 'junit.textui.TestRunner'
     [java] 'com.freiheit.gnupg.tests.GnuPGTestSuite'
     [java]
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
     [java] suite()
     [java] Failed to invoke suite():java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java] Could not create and run test suite: java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java] Java Result: 2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Why I got NullPointerException? What can I do to rapair it?

My environment:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

$ gpgme-config --version
1.4.3

$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20
...
```

I normally use GnuPG from this machine:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/mn/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
pub   2048R/62733741 2011-12-15
uid                  nopasswd
sub   2048R/902CAF09 2011-12-15

pub   2048R/AC75E4AD 2014-10-20
uid                  Test Space
sub   2048R/8309D68D 2014-10-20

pub   2048R/86AD2898 2014-11-24
uid                  admin
sub   2048R/14C8BB02 2014-11-24
....
```